# Debugging in Apache Karaf startup exception

Tags: apache-karaf

I am trying to setup debugging in `Apache Karaf` using this [link](http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/developers-guide/debugging.html).

After reaching the `YourKit` step I am getting the following error in my `cmd` prompt. Has anyone faced this issue before and guide me ahead?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried on my windows machine using karaf 3.0.0:

```
D:\java\apache-karaf-3.0.0>set KARAF_DEBUG=true

D:\java\apache-karaf-3.0.0>bin\karaf
karaf.bat: Enabling Java debug options: -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

So it works fine for me. Can you try with the 3.0.0 release?

Answer (score 0):

karaf debugging is quite simple.
If using Windows:
karaf.exe debug
if using unix/linux:
karaf.sh debug

no need to configure anything. Especially if you don't want to use a Profiler like YourKit you don't need to configure it.